# Node.JS - How would I do this regex?

Tags: javascript, regex

Well I have this:

```
var regex = /convertID\s(\d+)/
var match = regex.exec(message);
if(match != null)
{
//do stuff here
}
```

That works fine and it recognizes if someone writes "convertID NumbersHere".
However I want to have another one under it as well checking if there's a specific link, for example:

```
var regex = /convertID\shttp://anysitehere dot com/id/[A-Z]
var match = regex.exec(message);
if(match != null)
{
//do stuff here
}
```

So how would I make it check for an specific site with any letters after /id/?

Comment: You need to escape the `/` characters in the regexp.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use this:

```
var regex = /convertID\shttp:\/\/thesite.com\/id\/[A-Za-z]+/;
```

slashes must be escaped since the slash is used to delimit the pattern. You can avoid this creating explicitly an instance of RegExp class:

```
var regex = new RegExp("convertID\\shttp://thesite.com/id/[A-Za-z]+");
```

Comment: Thanks for the quick answer! So, \/ is needed for each slash?

Comment: @WoopWoopWoopWoop: Yes since the slash is used to delimit the pattern.

Comment: @WoopWoopWoopWoop: it is because you have escaped the last slash that is the end delimiter (and not a literal slash).

Comment: This: http://puu.sh/7ue0h.png
Returns: http://puu.sh/7ue0T.png

(I tried mthes[0] and [1] as well)
How would I go about doing so it cuts out everything except the [A-Za-z]+ ? (in this case ^ - only keep zzzz)

Comment: @WoopWoopWoopWoop: a good way is to read a basic tutorial about regex, javascript and capturing groups. I suggest you to take a look at the MDN documentation where you can find short examples and explanations.